# Can't login with hashed password - Mysqli PHP

Tags: php

I have hashed my password on the registration page with next code:

```
$c_pass = $_POST['c_pass'];
$storePassword = password_hash($c_pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
```

And on login page I have this code:

```
$customer_email = $_POST['c_email'];
$customer_pass = $_POST['c_pass'];
$select_customer = "select * from customers where customer_email='$customer_email' AND customer_pass='$customer_pass'";
```

When trying to log in, they pop-up me an error screen that my credentials not valid. I try to use

> if(password_verify($customer_password,$row['c_pass'])){

But noting help me, can someone write me solution for this because i can't find the solution.

Comment: [A hashed password is different every time you hash it.](https://3v4l.org/Fdjdv) You won't be able to compare a password hash to the hashed password in your database. Instead, search for the customer_email, grab the row, then use [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to see if they match.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `AND` from your `WHERE` clause because when user types his/her password on login form input, it will be non-hashed and therefore you will never retrieve the user by the composite condition email + password. Instead, you should find the user by identifier (username or email), then you should compare the raw password from login form password input against the hashed from the database. So take a look into the following:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'db_name');

// these are submitted input values from the login form which you handle
$email = $_POST['c_email'];
$password = $_POST['c_password'];

// build your query with prepared statements which will retrieve
// the user from the database with login form submitted email
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('select * from customers where customer_email = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
$customer = $result->fetch_assoc();

// here you compare the typed user login password versus the fetched user's password from the database by the provided user email
if ($customer && password_verify($password, $customer['c_pass'])) {
    // ok, so the password comparison match
} else {
    // invalid login or password
}
```